# MVC 4 validation failed when saving data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I am using Data Annotation to validate my form. I have used following:-

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The Start Date field is required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$", ErrorMessage = "Start Date must be in mm/dd/yyyy format.")]      
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
```

I am selecting date from jquery calender (format: mm-dd-yyyy)

When I save form it throws error "**Entity validation failed.**"

But if I remove regular expression it allows to save data.

Please provide the solution

Thanks

Comment: are you sure the regex is correct?

Comment: Your regex has a `/` separator, your calendar has `-` separator?

Comment: Replace the `/` separator in your regex with `-`

Comment: I am using "/"  as separator in calender.

Answer (score 1):

Very helful page to test regularexpression here http://regex101.com/

please update your code to that:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])-(19|20)\d{2}$",
ErrorMessage = "Start Date must be in mm-dd-yyyy format.")]
```